# res.render is not a function?

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

```
     const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const ejs = require("ejs");

const homeStartingContent = "L.";
const aboutContent = "Hac.";
const contactContent = "S.";

const app = express();
const PORT = 3000;
app.set("view engine", "ejs");

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.get("/", (res, req) => {
  res.render("home");
});
app.listen(PORT, function () {
  console.log("working");
})
```

Either I'm missing something incredibly simple, or the file i downloaded is out of date. I considered the 2nd option, so I reinstalled the dependencies. Still hasnt worked. I keep getting  error "'res.render' is not a function. I'm combed through this code. I seriously have no idea where I'm screwing up. I've even messed around and copied and pasted variants of it with a version that works on a different project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing parameters in incorrect sequence,
Here, you are passing response as first parameter,

```
app.get("/", (res, req) => {
  res.render("home");
});
```

while request is first parameter for any router method of expressJS, update it as below,

```
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.render("home");
});
```

Comment: seriously just wasted an hour messing around with this, then had to ask just for it to be me not putting it in the correct order. I truly do appreciate you checking it out and showing me.

Comment: @Drake: Please accept the answer, if this solved your issue -> https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers